# How exactly do I connect my domain to my apache2 VPS?

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, virtualhost, vps

I followed a tutorial last night on how to create a virtual host on Apache and later connected my domain to it using DNS A records. Someone today, I can't even connect to the domain as it says in Chrome that my domain could not be found.

All virtual host/DNS tutorials I've looked at have been muddy and unclear so I'm asking you - please point me to a great in depth tutorial on **how to connect my domain to my VPS using virtual host and DNS A records (or if there's a better way?)** or write one here and I'd be so glad.

Thank you so much!

Here's a picture of my DNS configuration on www.pcextreme.nl where I've bought my domain www.bonecountyroleplay.com. The IP to my VPS is **291.241.81.45**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vT0PV.png

On my VPS IP Apache site (291.241.81.45) I've made a subfolder called bonecountyroleplay.com and under that, public_html. I've then started a virtual host (which I guess I did wrong) to listen for the domain (bonecountyroleplay.com) and redirect that domain to the bonecountyroleplay.com/public_html folder.

Comment: Show us your config and we (maybe) can lead you to a solution. This is not a "here is my work do it for me" site! ;)

Comment: @deagh - I'm so sorry. I updated the question with a picture of the DNS configuration and some more in-depth of what I've done so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your domain's nameservers are not correct in the registrar record.

```
nameserver: ns1.volt-host.com
nameserver: ns2.volt-host.com
```

As your screenshot shows, they should be:

```
v1.pcextreme.nl
v2.pcextreme.nl
v3.pcextreme.eu
```

Since your domain seems to be registered with PCExtreme, you will need to contact them to have this error corrected.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! But do I actually need to have nameservers as I'll be connecting my domain with an A record to the VPS?

Comment: The nameservers are where those records are stored and served to the world! So yes, they must be correct or your site will not be reachable.